# IP SLA: tcpConnect frequency and jitter codec

Tags: cisco, sla, jitter, gns3

I am trying to generate different kinds of traffic with IP SLA on a c7200 router, I am using the simulation software GNS, so if required I can change my router.

My aim is to generate congestion to see how my network react. But I have a problem with the following attempt:

```
R3(config)#rtr 1
R3(config-rtr-jitter)#$type jitter dest-ipaddr 7.7.7.1 dest-port 16384 codec g711ulaw codec-numpackets 50 codec-size 160 codec-interval 20
type jitter dest-ipaddr 7.7.7.1 dest-port 16384 codec g711ulaw codec-numpackets  ^50 codec-size 160 codec-interval 20

% Invalid input detected at '^' marker.

R3(config-rtr-jitter)#
```

The indentation does not match on this copy-past, but this command seems not to work because "codec" parameter is not recognized. I have the same problem on a c3620 router. Could it be due to GNS3 ? (normally it should not, but you never know...)

Also I have another question: is it possible to specify the number and size of packets to send in a period of time (set by "frequency x") ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a code version issue - GNS3 doesn't support a router that can run a version of IOS code new enough to support the enhanced IP SLA configuration.

I can tell you're using "old" code because you're configuring IP sla with the "rtr" commands instead of "ip sla monitor" commands.  Unfortunately as I said you can't in my experience get new enough code on the models of router supported in GNS3.